# Div at the browser bottom

Tags: html, css

I use the below piece of code to align a div at the browser bottom

CSS:

```css
/* using the child selector to hide the
following body css from IE6 and earlier */
html>body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
 CCC
</div>
```

This works well when the page fits the page:

[image: works well]

But when the page length exceeds then if I scroll the page the div also getting scrolled top:

[image: not working well]

I have placed the footer div at the top top user control. There are some other controls after the footer div. Will that cause the issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

absolute is absolute relative to html body, and fixed is with respect to the frame

Difference and other values for [position tag are here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: As there are few controls after the div, the div appeared as shown in image :http://i.imgur.com/I9vVv.png. But I want this to be at the browser bottom

Comment: Take a div that floats to the bottom, and put those controls inside of that layer. AND I think position:fixed is part of the solution but not enough, you should be using my or danwellman's complete solution below, to get it properly working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sticky footer CSS: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should use **fixed** position instead of **absolute**.
Use this code:

```
/* using the child selector to hide the
following body css from IE6 and earlier */
html>body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for this http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page ?