# Align div in browser bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Refer the thread : [Div at the browser bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871671/div-at-the-browser-bottom)

Problem image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOIQz.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTU5U.png

I used all the methods and it all went in wain. Is there any method in Jquery to place a div at  the bottom if even the page is scrolled ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, you asked the question again. The answer that was given most points is the correct one. Now.. I would very much suggest you to use internet explorers developer tools, only they are quite crappy... You should get firefox and firebug and inspect that element that you are trying to get to stick at the bottom.Chances are that it has some other css that gives it `position: absolute` cause that is the way it's acting like. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/JEW3V/ <-- try to work your way forward with this.

Answer (score 1):

For browsers other than IE6, use `position: fixed` is enough:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed !important; /* IE6 hack */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
```

For IE6, a general approach is to register the `scroll` event and dynamically change the `top` style property of `#footer`

```
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');

// Test IE6
if (footer.currentStyle && 
    footer.currentStyle.position !== 'fixed') {
    // Set bottom to 'auto' because we would use top property
    footer.style.bottom = 'auto';
    // Only for IE6, so use window.attachEvent
    window.attachEvent(
        'onscroll',
        function() {
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var pageHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            var height = footer.offsetHeight;
            footer.style.top = (scrollTop + pageHeight - height) + 'px';
        }
    );
}
```